# What's the equivalent of Excel's `left(find(), -1)` in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have names in my dataset and they include parentheses. But, I am trying to clean up the names to exclude those parentheses.

Example: ABC Company (Somewhere, WY)

What I want to turn it into is: ABC Company

I'm using standard SQL with google big query.

I've done some research and I know big query has `left()`, but I do not know the equivalent of `find()`. My plan was to do something that finds the ( and then gives me everything to the left of -1 characters from the (.

Comment: Google's Standard SQL in Big Query includes [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace), which seems like the best choice to me...

Comment: I tried this -- SELECT
    RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(name, r'(%)','')) AS new_name
FROM table

The challenge is that I don't know how to pull out the (words) expression. T'he wildcard % isn't working here. What'd you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My plan was to do something that finds the ( and then gives me everything to the left of -1 characters from the (.

Good plan! In BigQuery Standard SQL - equivalent of `LEFT` is [`SUBSTR(value, position[, length])`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#substr) and equivalent of `FIND` is [`STRPOS(value1, value2)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#strpos)

With this in mind your query can look like (which is exactly as you planned)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH names AS (
  SELECT 'ABC Company (Somewhere, WY)' AS name 
)
SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, STRPOS(name, '(') - 1) AS clean_name 
FROM names
```

Usually, string functions are less expensive than regular expression functions, so if you have pattern as in your example - you should go with above version

But in more generic cases, when pattern to clean is more dynamic like in Graham's answer  - you should go with solution in Graham's answer

Comment: This is what I ended up going with, based on what you said

SELECT CASE WHEN name LIKE '%(%' THEN SUBSTRING(name, 1, STRPOS(name, '(') - 1) 
ELSE name END 
FROM name

Thanks Mikhail!

Answer (score 3):

Just use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace) + [TRIM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#trim). This will work with all variants (just not nested parentheses):

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  names AS (
  SELECT
    'ABC Company  (Somewhere, WY)' AS name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '(Somewhere, WY)  ABC Company' AS name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'ABC (Somewhere, WY) Company' AS name)
SELECT
  TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(name,r'\(.*?\)',''), ' ') AS cleaned
FROM
  names
```

[image]

Comment: What about whitespace between the LHS content and the text inside parentheses?

Comment: Updated to use `TRIM`

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this solution at the moment, but you can combine SUBSTR and INSTR. Like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(name, '(') > 0 THEN SUBSTR( name, 1, INSTR(name, '(') ) ELSE name END as name FROM table;
```

Comment: This is a generally good answer, but should a certain company not have a term in parentheses, the call to substring would return empty.

Comment: You are right, I updated the query to take this into consideration.

Comment: I tried this, but it said -- Function not found: INSTR at [1:18]. It's possible that google big query doesn't support instr()

Comment: @Sebastian Are you using the legacy version of BigQuery or the new one?  I have the feeling that maybe your version doesn't support the string functions we are using.

Comment: I'm using the new one, I believe

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT
    RTRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(names, r'([^(]*)')) AS new_name
FROM yourTable
```

The regex used here will greedily consume and match everything up until hitting an opening parenthesis.  I used `RTRIM` to remove any unwanted whitespace picked up by the regex.

Note that this approach is robust with respect to the edge case of an address record not having any term with parentheses.  In this case, the above query would just return the entire original value.

Comment: I tried this, but it made all of my name results null

Comment: @Sebastian I don't have BigQuery or your dataset in front of me, so I can't test my code other than to check the regex itself.